# R: Christmas Tree

Tags: r, tree

For an assignment, we need to draw a Christmas tree in R.
I've searched the internet and found some helpful pieces of advice, but at the end of the day, I don't know how to proceed and hope someone can help me.

This is my code so far.

```
#ctree: prints a Christmas tree on screen with size N
ctree <- function(N){
for (i in 1:N){
    width = sample("*",i,replace=T)
    cat(width,sep="-","\n")
    }   
cat(width[1],"\n")
}
```

This leaves me with the middle and right side of my tree (with N=4), which is great, but not enough.

```
*-
*-*-
*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-
*
```

I planned on reversing what I had (basically right-aligning the product of the function) to create the left side, subsequently delete the rightmost column of the left side and glue it together with the right side of the tree, creating a Christmas tree.

I really hope that someone can help me achieve this! Looking forward to your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `sample` for this? `rep` seems like a better choice. Also, you are almost there. Switch `*` and `_` in your code and adjust how often `_` is repeated.

Comment: Did you try the plan you mentioned? If so, did something go wrong?  We shouldn't be doing your homework, but we can help with errors you run into.

Comment: Inspiration: [Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n)

Comment: Hey, half a tree is better than none!  :-)

Comment: OK, seriously: was your assignment specifically to draw one using ASCII code in the console, or are you allowed to use graphics tools to plot a (presumably much better-looking) tree in a graphics window?

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks a lot for the comments. By now I found another way to create the bloody christmas tree (by concatenating N-i instances of whitespaces and asterisks in a row as the counter progresses). 

And yes Carl, half a tree definitely is better than none. XD I wasn't able to execute my initial 'plan', simply because I had no idea where to start (so I was hoping you could offer some functions which might have proven helpful, obviously I didn't want you guys to spell it out for me ;). And definitely, Roland, rep is a much neater choice, don't know why I didn't think of it. (:

Comment: Oh and @CarlWitthoft, no, we weren't supposed to use graphic tools. (;

Comment: That's a shame, because I remember this Christmas tree on R-Bloggers last Christmas, which I thought was very nice: http://www.r-bloggers.com/merry-christmas-2/

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested: this is what I ended up doing in R to create a Christmas tree.

```
#ctree: prints a Christmas tree on screen with amount of branch levels N
ctree <- function(N){
filler = "*"
blank = ""

for (i in 1:N){
    row = c(sample(blank,N-i,replace=T),sample(filler,i,replace=T),sample(blank,N-i,replace=T))
    cat(row,"\n")
    }   
cat(c(sample(blank,(N-1),replace=T),sample(filler,1,replace=T),sample(blank,(N-1),replace=T)),"\n")
} #ctree
```

This being the result! My own happy little (or big, whatever floats your boat) tree.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `sample` to repeat a value n times, that function is supposed to be used to randomly sample n-times from a set. Use `rep(value,ntimes)` instead...

Comment: Yeah, @digEmAll, Roland pointed it out to me earlier, but I only saw that comment after I had made this function. I utterly agree though, rep is much better and much more appropriate. (:

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more succinct version:

```
ctree <- function(N=10){
  for (i in 1:N) cat(rep("",N-i+1),rep("*",i),"\n")
  cat(rep("",N),"*\n")
}

ctree()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code came from someone else.  I wish I could credit them but I have lost the source. The tree it produces is beautiful, and perhaps you could modify it for your purposes.

```
part <- list(x0=0,y0=0,x1=0,y1=1,
             branch1=NULL,branch2=NULL,extend=NULL,
             lwd=1,depth=0,col='springgreen')

par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
segplot <- function(tree) {
  if (is.null(tree)) return()
  segments(tree$x0,tree$y0,tree$x1,tree$y1,
           col=tree$col,
           lwd=tree$lwd)
  segplot(tree$branch1)
  segplot(tree$branch2)
  segplot(tree$extend)
}
#segplot(part)

grow <- function(tree) {
  if (is.null(tree) ) return(NULL)

  tree$lwd=tree$lwd*1.2
  if (tree$lwd>2.5) tree$col <- 'brown'
  if (is.null(tree$extend)) {
    tree$extend <- list(
      x0=tree$x1,
      y0=tree$y1,
      x1=rnorm(1,1,.03)*(2*tree$x1-tree$x0),
      y1=(rnorm(1,.98,.02)+.02*(tree$x1==tree$x0))*(2*tree$y1-tree$y0),
      branch1=NULL,
      branch2=NULL,
      extend=NULL,
      lwd=1,
      depth=tree$depth,
      col=tree$col
    )
    length=sqrt((tree$x1-tree$x0)^2 + (tree$y1-tree$y0)^2)
    angle <- asin((tree$x1-tree$x0)/length)
    branch <- list(
      x0=(tree$x1+tree$x0)/2,
      y0=(tree$y1+tree$y0)/2,
      branch1=NULL,
      branch2=NULL,
      extend=NULL,
      lwd=1,
      depth=tree$depth,
      col=tree$col
    )
    shift <- rnorm(2,.5,.1)
    branch$x0 <- shift[1]*tree$x1+(1-shift[1])*tree$x0
    branch$y0 <- shift[1]*tree$y1+(1-shift[1])*tree$y0
    length=length*rnorm(1,.5,.05)
    co <- runif(1,.35,.45)
    branch$x1 <- branch$x0+sin(angle+co)*length

    branch$y1 <- branch$y0+cos(angle+co)*length
    tree$branch1 <- branch
    branch$x0 <- shift[2]*tree$x1+(1-shift[2])*tree$x0
    branch$y0 <- shift[2]*tree$y1+(1-shift[2])*tree$y0
    co <- runif(1,.35,.45)
    branch$x1 <- branch$x0+sin(angle-co)*length
    branch$y1 <- branch$y0+cos(angle-co)*length
    tree$branch2 <- branch    
  } else {
    tree$branch1 <- grow(tree$branch1)
    tree$branch2 <- grow(tree$branch2)
    tree$extend <- grow(tree$extend)
  }
  tree$depth <- tree$depth+1
  if (tree$depth>2)  tree$col <- 'green'
  if (tree$depth>4)  tree$col <- 'darkgreen'
  if (tree$depth>6)  tree$col <- 'brown'

  tree
}
tree <- part
for (i in 1:9) tree <- grow(tree) 
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(x=c(-3,3),y=c(0,9),type='n',axes=FALSE,xlab='',ylab='')
segplot(tree)
```

Comment: I think I saw this on R-bloggers one time. I was amazed

Comment: Wow, this tree is beautiful. Thanks for sharing. (: